# Pyinstaller : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythagorean'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

I use "numerology" module installed in my venv. I need to make an .exe file. https://github.com/compuuteio/numerology

I go this error when I launch my .exe

```
import numerology # PyInstaller PYZ
# pythagorean not found in PYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "extract.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "numerology\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythagorean'
```

Pythagorean import from numerology also give me error in PyCharm editor.

```
from numerology import Pythagorean
```

`Cannot find reference 'Pythagorean' in '__init__.py'`

Here is where is in **init**.py

```
from pythagorean.numerology import Numerology as Pythagorean
```

I have tried "--hidden-import" with either "numerology" or "pythagorean" in my pyinstaller command. I still have the issue.

Comment: Can you try to add `--collect-all muerology` to your pyinstaller query.